# Filtering ODBC data import

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, odbc

I'm trying to copy a database to a Microsoft SQL server through a VtrinLib ODBC-driver. I am using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard with the .Net Framework Data Provider for ODBC.

Every few minutes the destination SQL server should check the source for new records. Since all records have a date and time value, I would like to write a query that should only take records after the max date/time value in the destination SQL server table.

```
SELECT *
FROM Source_Table_A
WHERE Source_Column_TimeStamp > [destination date/time value from last import]
```

My problem is, how to specify [destination date/time value from last import], since I don't know how to make a reference to the destination table?

Comment: Subquery maybe? `> (SELECT TOP 1 timestamp FROM dest ORDER BY timestamp dest)`

Comment: Presumably these 2 objects are not on the same instance, @Charlieface , as otherwise I don't see why the OP would be using the Import/Export wizard.

Comment: Side note, `timestamp`, in SQL Server, is a deprecated synonym for `rowversion`, which is a `binary(8)` value. Do you actually mean a `timestamp`, or do you mean a date and time value?

Comment: Apparently your "process" needs to **remember** the maximum value retrieve during the prior import and use it in the subsequent import. The wizard has no way of doing that itself - you need a different approach. However, you could use the wizard to generate a SSIS package to use as a starting point for adding this logic.

Comment: @Larnu: Thank you for your correction. I have to work a little on my vocabulary :)